# Remove content from webview android

Tags: java, android, xml, webview

Is it possible to remove some parts (iframe, dropdowns, links) from a website I want to show in a webview, I am using the webview for login purposes, since the webapp of the website and my native app has somewhat same features I don't want the user to access the webapp through the webview layout of my app. If I could remove some parts (footer navigation links, site map
) of the webpage I could restrict the user from accessing the webapp am I able to make you understand?

Thanks!